# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Enrollment>> always returns 10 results

Tags: c#, json.net

My JsonConvert.DeserializeObject> is working, but returns a maximum of only 10 results. I know that the data item I am GETing in the API has 24 records, but only 10 are returned.

Here is the JSON:

```
    [
{
"id":2227,
"user_id":441,
"grades":
    {"html_url":"https://...",
    "current_score":91.26,
    "current_grade":null,
    },
"sis_account_id":"11",
"user":
    {"id":441,
     "name":"Nicholas Bailey",
    }
},
```

Here are the classes:

```
        public class Grade
{
    public string html_url { get; set; }
    public decimal? current_score { get; set; }
    public string current_grade { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
public class Enrollment
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public int? user_id { get; set; }
    public Grade grades { get; set; }
    public string sis_account_id { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my code:

```
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://(some uri)");

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();

    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore;

    var outObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Enrollment>>(content, settings);
```

I'm wondering if there is a property in JsonSerializerSettings that controls this. I have searched google but cannot find anything. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a full example of the returned json string?

Comment: There is nothing in Json.Net which limits the number of items deserialized from the JSON.  More than likely the web API you are calling has a limit on the number of items returned, or groups the items into "pages" of results.  If so, it probably also has one or more parameters you can pass to change how many items are returned at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked api has a paging feature? Perhaps there is a page parameter on api side?

Comment: Thanks. I did check the api and they have a default of 10 records returned. I got the parameter to increase it and now I'm getting all my records.

Comment: The solution is to add a page parameter to the URL.